# Multiple Rails vers on same machine + rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake

I've been running a Rails 3.2 with Ruby 1.9.3 for a while now.  Recently I added Rails 5.1 and Ruby 2.4.

I used rvm to install Ruby2.4.

Today I had occasion to cd into one of my old projects and run `rake db:migrate`, and I got the following message:

```
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 12.0.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
```

Prepending 'bundle exec' did solve the problem but for my knowledge I would like to understand what happened.  I thought the whole point of a Gem file within the project was to lock in the required gems.

So somewhere on my machine clearly there is still rake 0.9.2.2 but why did my command 'rake db:migrate' not use that automatically?

Comment: The mad thing is I just looked at my gemfile and it has NO MENTION of rake anywhere.  This is even more confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason**: Some of the gem might have locked rake gem to that version.You are getting this as version of rake inside gemlock file is different than the one you have already installed.

**Solution1:**

```
bundle update
```

**Solution2:**

edit the gemlock file. open Gemfile.lock and change

```
rake (0.9.2.2) to rake (12.0.0)
```

**Solution3**:

remove Gemfile.lock and run `bundle install` once again.This will create
Gemfile.lock once again.

Comment: Thanks krishnar, do I do this inside the project directory?

Comment: many thanks for your detailed answer.  I'll try this tomorrow.

Comment: I ran bundle update and now it's installed rake 12.1.0 and it's complaining that I have rake 12.0.0 activated.  My question remains why when I run rake does it not use what is already in that projects gems?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @nexar check with other solution

Comment: I did Solution3 and now it's working correctly.  However I would still like to understand why when I run rake does it not use what is already in that projects gems? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @nexar now you have rake gem installed in your project directory. It won't ask.  Accept and upvote my answer if it was useful